# Move one folder back in server MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to display an image in another project from an MVC project. While accessing the image from MVC, i need to go a folder back ( or no need of the View folder name ) in the path. Following is the controller code for the view  Views\Booking

```
 public virtual ActionResult ResendEticket(BookingViewModel resendTicketModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resendTicketModel.Email))
            {
                BookingService resendEticket = new BookingService();
                string result = resendEticket.ResendEticket(Convert.ToInt32(resendTicketModel.BookingReference), resendTicketModel.Email);

                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, result);
                }
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to do resend ticket due to system error");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Booking");
    }
```

The path i am getting in the receiving side currently  is 
  **C:\ Projects\Booking\Invoices\Templates\images\logo_eticket.png**

What  i need is  **C:\ Projects\Invoices\Templates\images\logo_eticket.png**

In the receiving side , i am using following code

```
TaxInvoiceFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(mtxr.TaxInvoiceFilePath);
```

I may not be able to change anything on above line, as this is shared with other applications. 
How can i move HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath one step back so that all will be fine

Comment: What is `mtxr` ? how and where you set the property value of that ?

Comment: mtxr.TaxInvoiceFilePath value is obtained from common database

Comment: Why not store it properly in the first place ?

Comment: As mentioed, that value  is used in different application and cannot update.

Comment: So if you are trying to remove the `Booking` part of the string, you can do a `Replace("Booking","")`

Comment: I cannot update that side as it is shared with different application. Is there anything i can do from the inital calling side